# AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux 2018.03) ran instance yum update and now yum gives an error about NSS_3.34

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I ran yum update and tomcat was not working. I then tried to downgrade nss but yum is not working at all and gives me the following error PLEASE HELP:

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

/usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.34' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.15 (default, Nov 28 2018, 22:38:08) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Comment: Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Comment: Yup. I know how stack works - I have been on this thing since 2008. Your answer did not help as yum was broken - I could neither upgrade nor downgrade nor update nor install nor uninstall anything.

Comment: Thought would update this ticket: we finally got rid of that production linux EC2 instance with the integrated firefox. Happy to report that I will never have to worry about that again for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not make any sense and I have no idea why this worked:

I unzipped a copy of firefox into /usr/local/ specifically [firefox-64.0.tar.bz2](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/64.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-64.0.tar.bz2)

And it just worked. As this is a headless server that was configured and setup by someone else I have no idea why it has firefox in the first place or why yum would be expecting a lib from that dir.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox provides `libnss-*.so` library, and so does `nss-*.rpm` package. Once you *downgraded* the `nss` package yum stopped working because it no longer had a recent-enough `libnss-*.so` library available (newer than NSS_3.34). When you unzipped Firefox to /usr/local/ you have provided the required `libnss` library in new-enough version and `yum` is happy again.

You should upgrade the `nss` package back to what's in the repository instead or relying on the Firefox libs because at the moment although `yum` works it's got broken package dependencies and you will face various issues during future `yum upgrade` runs.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: But why is yum (lib url I guess) depending on a Firefox lib? Shouldn’t it be depending on a package from amazon Linux?

Comment: @JimFord it doesn't depend on *firefox lib*, it depends on `libnss` which also happens to be included in the firefox tarball. Hence unzipping the firefox package accidentally provided a suitable `libnss` for yum. The correct solution is to install Amazon Linux `nss` package with version 3.34 or higher. Then this package will provide `libnss` for yum and you'll be able to remove the firefox directory.

Comment: I couldn’t even do the downgrade as yum was not functioning after the yum update command. Curl was looking at the Firefox nss rather than the package that was installed by the update.